# What is the command for removing windows shortcut virus?

Tags: windows, virus-removal

We have to insert our pendrive (flash drive) at cyber cafes or other public places. So, it is almost impossible for us to ensure that systems we plug into are malware-free.  As a result, we experience a recurring problem of our pendrives becoming infected.

One type of malware that has been a problem is a *shortcut virus*, which renders all my pendrive folders hidden.  When I view the drive contents, I see nothing except a shortcut file. But my folders appear when I search.

How to solve this?

Comment: what is "shortcut virus affected PC" ? a pc infected with virus?

Comment: @Kelmen Yes, "a pc infected with one kind of virus that makes all folders in it hidden and create a shortcut file", sorry for my bad English.

Comment: @manetsus - If you realize the grammar is bad you should take steps to correct it.

Comment: @Ramhound Go ahead, the `edit` button is there for other users for a reason.

Comment: @cybermonkey - I encourage people to fix their own mistakes.  I leave my editing duties to things they cannot do because of their reputation.  I also leave fixing grammatical mistakes to people that are better at that particular skillset.

Comment: In addition to what you've attempted, you may also want to [check out my answer](http://superuser.com/a/976275/167187) on removing similar infections.

Comment: "Sometimes" indicates that this is a repeating problem, which should never be the case.  It means that you aren't fixing the underlying problem.  If the cause is malware, you need to eradicate it completely to prevent reinfection.  If you can't identify the malware, or your A/V software isn't removing it, try the fixes in our canonical thread on malware: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Comment: @fixer1234 Actually, we could not control it. Because, we have to insert our pendrive (flash drive) in cyber cafe or other public places. So, it is almost impossible for us to go every public place and eradicate that. That's why it is a repeating problem for us, we have to care about only our drive.

Comment: In that kind of environment, it would be good practice to run a malware scan on the flash drive before accessing anything on it.

Comment: @fixer1234 I appreciate your edit. Thanks for rephrasing my question and  making it better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `cmd`in "Open:" field. Then click "OK" or enter. This would bring you to the command line terminal.

Then type the following command replacing `X` with the drive letter of your flash drive/pendrive and then enter:

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d X:\*.*
```

If you eager to see more about this command see [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx) documentation from microsoft.